# Using session (memory) vs revalidation (CPU)

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I have a web page that plots data points on the visible area of a map based on a set of fifteen criteria. The user can pan or zoom the map, which will trigger an AJAX call to the database, via a query script, to generate new data based on the criteria and the bounding box of the viewable area of the map. The current implementation is such that the criteria will be validated once, via a validation script, and stored in a `$_SESSION` array that is loaded onto the query script (unless the criteria changes). The validation script consists of a series of `preg_match` function and conditional `if...else` statements.

Another way I can implement the above to save memory is by having the query script validate all fifteen criteria every time the user moves the map. The trade-off is a higher CPU consumption for the validation in exchange of lower memory usage by doing away with `$_SESSION` array. How do I quantify the trade-off between these two options to decide which is the better approach given that there are many users connecting to the server at any one time.

Comment: I am not expert in such these questions...but select a way which has best performance for the user

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get reliable data is to test both implementations simulating the expected peak number of concurrent users.

If that is not feasible, I'd recommend caching (session), since it is much easier (and cheaper) to add some RAM than more CPU power.